# OnTouchStart, onTouchEnd in button tag recognize click event

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I want to create a button, that will display a string on hover when using a computer with a mouse, and for a touch screen, when the button is pressed the string will display.
In the tag button, I defined: onMouseOver,onMouseOut, onTouchStart, onTouchEnd.

```
const [isShowDescription, setIsShowDescription] = useState(false); /* state to show or hide the description */

const displayDescription = () => {
    setIsShowDescription(true); /* show the description */ 
};

const notDisplayDescription = () => {
    setIsShowDescription(false); /* hide the description */
};

<button className='start-button' onMouseOver={displayDescription} onMouseOut={notDisplayDescription} onTouchStart={displayDescription} onTouchEnd={notDisplayDescription}>
   Click here to start
</button>
```

When I am using the touch screen, the onTouchStart event is called when pressed in the button on the screen, and when released, the onTouchEnd is called, but in the first time that I pressed also the onMouseOver is called. I tried to add preventDefault() and the onMouseOver was not called, but I receive an error: 'Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation'.

What can I do? How can I prevent the click on the first time?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you've implemented  the preventDefault(). Adding it like this I don't get the error you mentioned:

```
const handleTouchStart = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent default touch behavior 
  displayDescription();
};

const handleTouchEnd = (event) => {
  notDisplayDescription();
};
```

maybe try adding:

```
const handleMouseOver = () => {
  if (!isButtonTouched) {
    displayDescription();
  }
};

const handleMouseOut = () => {
  if (!isButtonTouched) {
    notDisplayDescription();
  }
};
```

then add the events on the button:

```
onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I get the error: 'Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation'

Comment: see above if it helps